# ArcMap 10.3.1 Crashes when trying to change the version

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.3, versioning

I'm using ArcMap 10.3.1 when I have a data connection to another user (For example change from Tom's version to Jim's version of the SDE) or default and attempt to change the version to my own ArcMap crashes immediately. When selecting the debug report it also crashes. Any ideas?

Windows 7,
ArcMap 10.3.1

Tried the following:

- Restart computer
- Repair ArcMap install
- Delete Normal.mxt file
- Reset ESRI user profile

[EDIT - 8/3/2016]
Issue is back previous fix does not seem to be working. Noticed that if log into another computer with my version I can change the version without issue. So points to something wrong with either this install of ArcMap or the computer, but not on the versioning side of things.

Comment: If ArcGIS is crashing, you really ought to be talking to Esri Tech Support.  GIS SE is not intended to replace vendor tech support, but if we are to help, you'd need to provide quite a few more details on the RDBMS product, the connection client software, and what you mean by "to another user".

Comment: Mean by "to another user", For example change from Tom's version to Jim's version of the SDE

Comment: Please **edit the question** in response to comments

Comment: You still need to **edit the question** to contain details about the RDBMS in use, the version or the enterprise geodatabase, the database client software, the operating systems involved,...  "data connection to another user" still makes no sense to me, even with your clarification -- as what user is the connection made?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having a separate issue with the search bar not displaying and giving me the following error. "E511D6E5-9B6A-4D5D-8FE6-BC81669B81B5". Google that found the link above and ran the SearchFix.zip, it fixed the search bar so figure may as well see if it fixed the version crash issue and it did.

[Running SearchFix.zip fixed my issues](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/40352)

Comment: Do you mean SearchFix.zip? And out of curiosity, what made you try that? Was it suggested by ESRI support?

Comment: @ian I was having a separate issue with the search bar not displaying and giving me the following error. "E511D6E5-9B6A-4D5D-8FE6-BC81669B81B5". Google that found the link above and ran the SearchFix.zip, it fixed the search bar so figure may as well see if it fixed the version crash issue and it did.